# Sort cell array in a dictionary sorting fashion?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have a `100x3` cell array, with each element being a string. Now I wish to sort it according to the 1st column. I can easily do this

```
sorted1 = sortrows(data, 1);
```

However, I don't want to stop here. I **wish to further sort it according to the 2nd column.** Of course, this sorting cannot destroy the 1st sorting. In other words, it is quite similar to **how the dictionary is sorted.**

How may I do this?

Comment: Doe each string in the first column have different length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) keeps sorting by other columns, if you specify them too:

```
>> data = {'banana','blue','cow'; 
           'zebra','ape','frog';
           'banana', 'apple', 'pear';
           'banana', 'apple', 'orange'};
>> sorted1 = sortrows(data, 1)
sorted1 = 
    'banana'    'blue'     'cow'   
    'banana'    'apple'    'pear'  
    'banana'    'apple'    'orange'
    'zebra'     'ape'      'frog'  
>> sorted1 = sortrows(data, [1 2])
sorted1 = 
    'banana'    'apple'    'pear'  
    'banana'    'apple'    'orange'
    'banana'    'blue'     'cow'   
    'zebra'     'ape'      'frog'
```

Note that by excluding column 3 with `[1 2]`, it doesn't waste time sorting by column 3 (`'pear'` still comes before `'orange'`).

Comment: Does `sortrows(data)` do the same thing?

Comment: @David I am not sure, but even if it does, this is still useful, as the first 2 columns are enough for me. I won't waste the time sorting according to the 3rd column. :)

Comment: @FarticlePilter Right, I updated the answer with a `[1 2]` column specification.

Comment: @chappjc Sorry, I meant in general. Are there any reasons for using `sortrows(data,1:length(data))` rather than just `sortrows(data)`? I understand that in this case you want `sortrows(data,[1 2])`, but if you wanted to use all columns, is there a difference?

Comment: @David I get what you are saying, and I don't think it really makes sense to do `1:size(data,2)` now that you mention it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055139/matlab-textscan-reading-result-is-a-nested-cell-array  Can you please help with this as well? I really appreciate that!

Comment: @chappjc OK cool, it just struck me as a little odd and I wondered whether there was something clever going on. Thanks!